# Why http and not https? kubectl cluster-info "kubernetes master running"

Tags: https, kubernetes, kube-apiserver

I've googled for hours and I can't seem to find the info. This might be a simple question... My question is this:

I have a big script to start up K8s. When everything is up and running and I do a `kubectl cluster-info` I get `kubernetes master is running on http://...`. EVERY example I read online says the result should be `https://...`

My question is what file/yaml/property/etc makes kubernetes master run http vs https?

I have both ports (80/443) defined in my kube-apiserver.yaml file. Do I have to get things working with the "insecure-port=0" in apiserver? Or can master run https without this?

Answer (score 0):

That command echoes whatever url kubectl is configured to speak to the apiserver on. `kubectl config view` displays the content of the kubeconfig file kubectl is using (specified in $KUBECONFIG, --kubeconfig, or ~/.kube/config by default)

Comment: Nothing in $KUBECONFIG. I looked at the kubeconfig file and the ~/.kube/config and they both have minimal text in them...

"apiversion: v1, clusters, contexts, current-context, kind: Config, preferences: users: -name: kubuser user: token: --help"